# Android: Posting events to message queue of View

Tags: android, view

I have the following problem:
My app has a thread that updates the game state. The app needs to make a change to the state of the View object, triggered by this thread.
The documentation for View states that it should only be modified from the UI thread, and that a Handler should be used to place and handle events.

Yet, there is a function post() in View where I can post a Runnable object that will execute in the UI thread without involvement of Handler. Can I not call this function from threads other than the UI thread??

I'm confused!

Comment: Not quite related, but Check out `AsyncTask` which is a thread and might help you as it's progress/result method runs on UI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use View.post(). Internally it uses a handler to post the Runnable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run some arbitrary code on the UI thread from a background thread, you can use Activity's runOnUiThread():

```
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    });
```